# how to run ivr on outbound call on asterisk 1.4

Tags: voip, asterisk, ivr

I want to know how to run an ivr on a outbound call.

I did the the settings in extensions.conf of asterisk like this.

```
[outgoing]    ;context
exten => 1567XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/101010@ip)  ;the call is successfully route on this number
exten => 1567xxxx,1,Answer() 
exten => 1567xxxx,n,Wait(1)
exten => 1567xxxx,n,Playback(hello-world)   ;but i want this ivr to be play when end user pick                                                                               up the call
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use macro at Dial command:

```
[outgoing]    ;context
exten => 1567XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/101010@ip,,M(call))
[macro-call]
exten => s,1,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => s,n,MacroExit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create outbound call and put other side of call to your context. Please check this article: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Note: if you are gooing create dialler, that is realy bad idea. Better got opensource one or hire professional. It will be alot of issues in this path.

Answer (score 0):

You have got two possible options. One is use the "Orignate" command. See http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+Originate for an example.

The other one, which is what I favor in my solutions, since it does not require AMI, is using spooled call files. See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+Files for how to do them. The trick, and I cannot stress it enough, is to create the spool file in /tmp and then "move" the file into the ../spool/asterisk/outgoing directory.

If you assign a unique channel variable key/value to the spooled call, you can then pick it up with your dial plan and route the call appropriately.

If you are building a batch dialer system, at its most fundamental is a database application that creates call spool files once a minute, equal to the number of lines your system has that are on-hook.  Complexity of your spooling system increases fairly rapidly if you want to worry about predictive/ optimized dialing, or passing calls to agents.

Answer (score 0):

Creating outbound calls in a spool-like way is not as easy as suggested by MichelV69 - I mean, it is that easy, but things start to get downhill fast as soon as you start having new requirements. I totally agree with the article here http://www.wombatdialer.com/manuals/WD_UserManual-chunked/ar01s01.html#_why_was_wombatdialer_created because that's what you'll be facing